# how to change data coming from api in an activity according to click at different textView

Tags: java, android, api, android-layout

Now I have a project I finished most of it but I have 3 textView when I click at any one of them I should get some data from api in another activity....How can I change the data from the activity by clicking on any textView ....I will share more info to explain what I mean ... frist I implemented a page that View the Bitcoin Price Index (BPI) in real-time from api file that view

1. time
2. description
3. currency name
4. USD rate
5. GBP rate
6. EUR rate
   now  By clicking on any of the items (USD,GBP and EUR rate), a document details screen should be presented. This screen
   should include:
7. - The Code.
8. - The Symbol.
9. - Description.
10. - Rate

I put these USD,GBP and EUR rate in textView ...now I need to change data in the page by clicking at one of them I do not know how can I do that !

I used this code in the page that view the details of data:

```
public class des_screen extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textViewcode;
TextView textViewsymbol;
TextView textViewdesc;
TextView textViewrate;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_des_screen);
    textViewcode = findViewById(R.id.code);
    textViewsymbol = findViewById(R.id.symbol);
    textViewdesc = findViewById(R.id.desc);
    textViewrate = findViewById(R.id.Rate);
    conectToApi();
}
private void conectToApi() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject bpi = jsonObject.getJSONObject("bpi");
                            //USD
                            JSONObject usdObject = bpi.getJSONObject("USD");
                            String codeUsd = usdObject.getString("code");
                            String symbolUsd = usdObject.getString("symbol");
                            String descUsd = usdObject.getString("description");
                            String rateUsd = usdObject.getString("rate");

                            textViewcode.setText(codeUsd.toString());
                            textViewsymbol.setText(symbolUsd.toString());
                            textViewdesc.setText(descUsd.toString());
                            textViewrate.setText(rateUsd.toString());


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

}

Comment: You should edit the question and show us some of the relevant code. Your question is too broad/vague to be able to give you any useful help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: thank u soo much for your time and interest. I am really sorry for my vague question. I tried to add more details and explain what I mean.